# How to open mutiple tabs within a browser using Capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara, selenium-webdriver

I need to open multiple tabs within a single browser and i need switch over all the tabs.

Give me your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i'm not sure of your question. please clarify me are you trying to open a tab by clicking a button or link or something like that.

Comment: Exactly i'm clicking the link and it's opening the new tab. And i need to switch over the new tab. And one more thing i want to know how to open tabs using capybara? Guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so strong in capybara. so, i'm giving solution to switch over between tabs using selenium.

For a instance you clicks a button in a web page and it will open a new page.

The new page may open in a `new tab in the same browser window` or `in a new browser window`. That is not controlled by selenium. It will control by the browser which you using.

For a instance take firefox, goto `tools->ptions-> tabs-> open new windows in a new tab instead` check the option. For example, if you clicks a button it will opens a page only in the new tab of a same browser window. For a sake if you unchecked mean it will open a page in the new browser window. Likewise every browser has its own settings.

Try this code:

```
 new Actions(driver)
.sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")), Keys.CONTROL)
.sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")), Keys.NUMPAD2)
.build().perform();
```

In above Keys.NUMPAD2 refers that you are gonna move to the second tab in the session.
You can move to Third, Fourth, etc... by giving NUMPAD3, NUMPAD4, etc... respectively. Here i am using windows OS, if you are in some other OS use their shortcuts.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this exact function in Ruby:

```rb
page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(page.driver.browser.window_handles.last)
```